# Should I wait for my answer to be moved or should I post it again?

Tags: support, flags

Recently, I self-flagged [an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33898435/1101509) on StackOverflow. Why? Well, because I stumbled upon it by checking my profile and realized I posted it in the wrong place.

It was actually supposed to answer [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/589469/) on AskUbuntu and I do not know how it got there. Maybe I was very distracted and wrote with the wrong tab open.

Anyway, when I flagged my answer, I explained the situation and asked that my answer be moved in the correct thread. It was deleted instead. Of course I am fine with that, because it was in the wrong place, that's why I flagged it even if I was going to basically lose my small reputation. :D

But my question is: will it be moved later on or should I re-write it as a new answer on AskUbuntu? I am not quite familiar with how these cross-site issues are handled.

In case answers cannot be moved, why isn't there a notification to inform the user that the answer has been deleted?

Comment: Afaik answers cannot be migrated. You have to repost it yourself.

Comment: I'm about 100% sure that answers can't be moved to a different SE site. You'll have to do that yourself. Migrations are for questions, not answers.

Comment: Ah ok, I have updated my question with a side-question. By the way, if you post them as answers I will accept one of them and upvote both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No one, including staff, can move an answer to another question for you - not even on the same site. The closest tool we have is the merge tool, which moves *all* answers to the other question (we can't single out just one) and requires they actually be duplicates first.

Your answer was merely deleted because you explained that you posted it in the wrong place. There was no call to take any other action in the flag text, so the moderator likely just assumed you wanted it deleted. If you had directly asked for it to be moved there, you would have gotten a message from the moderator that it's not possible.

If you think it should be posted on the AskUbuntu question, then you'll need to post it there yourself.

Comment: I see. I assumed it was clear that I was asking for something I though was possible... I mean, I can delete my own answers, so there would have been no need to flag it if I just wanted it to be deleted, right?

Comment: @Andrea You'd be surprised how many people ask us to delete things they can delete themselves.

Comment: Hehe ok, thanks for the clarification. I have posted my answer on AskUbuntu.